# Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.ArrayList

Tags: winforms, collections, c#-3.0, generic-collections

Here is my code

```
   private static ArrayList GetFirstObjectFromDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
    {
        foreach (ArrayList arr in dictionary.Values) //error 
        {
            return arr;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

It causes error "Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.ArrayList'".

Comment: Your **dictionary.Values** s type is **Dictionary<string,string>.ValueCollection**. So you can't cast it directly ArrayList and this code is not look meaningful! Can you explain what you want to do?

Comment: @Furkan Ekinci -Actually i want to take every item in dictionary to ArrayList in type of object,Before implementing Dictionary i have used hashtable for the same piece of code,due to performance reason i have changed data structure to Dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use KeyValuePair for reach dictionary's items.

```
private static ArrayList GetFirstObjectFromHashTable(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
{
    ArrayList aLst = new ArrayList();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in dictionary)
    {
        aLst.Add(pair.Value);
    }

    return aLst;
}
```

[This page](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary) might help you to understand foreach using with dictionaries.